# How to keep http connection alive for React Native's fetch method

Tags: react-native, fetch, keep-alive

I am trying to use RN's `fetch()` method with http connection alive.
I tried with header 'Connection: keep-alive' but it does not seem to work. I cannot use `http.Agent` because `http` module is not supported in React Native. I searched but cannot find an alternative module.(XmlHttpRequest does not work also)

Question: What can I do to keep http connection alive in React Native's environment?

My ultimate purpose is to authenticate a NTLM server in React Native's JavaScriptCore, the authentication needs keep-alive http connection. Any other suggestion is also appreciated.

Comment: any news for this question?..

Answer (score 2):

On Android (and presumably similarly on iOS), the OkHttp client used by ReactNative will by default keep either a Http/1.1 or Http/2 connection alive and reuse it.  You should check whether the server is closing the response.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#HTTP_1.1

Answer (score 0):

We created the native module in android/ios to open network connection in JAVA and Objective C and emit events on response.